# How to handle INT overflow on limited RAM devices (any language)?

Tags: language-agnostic, int, overflow, ram

I have a task in school where I have to answer this question:

"A couple of students make a calendar program where a days "absolute daynumber" is defined as the amount of days from January 1st year 0 to the current day. On many smaller computers the maximum value for a Int is 32767. What can happen if we disregard this? How can you solve this issue?"

The question kind of confuses me. I currently work in Python and from what I have read Python automatically handles Int overflows by converting the Int to a Long and other programming languages do similar things (like for example wrapping around to a negative number, AKA 32768 becomes -32767). If programming languages didn't automatically handle overflows I would imagine that you would simply get an error if the number goes over 32767... right?

If you wanted to print the "absolute daynumber" (assuming its over 32767 and you can only use Int's) you wouldn't be able to because you can't store the value in a Int. It would be impossible. If you wanted to just print today's date you could just take it from the PC BIOS or use Unix time instead.

For me it seems like the answer to this question depends on what exactly you want the program to do. But my teacher says no. He says that none of my answers are correct. I don't exactly understand what kind of answer he wants and this is supposed to be a easy question since I have only done programming for about 2 months now. What am I missing that is so obvious? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: `if variable > 32768: raise OverflowError`?

Comment: Use a larger capacity variable, such as an *unsigned int*, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, `int32_t`, or `int64_t`.  In assembly language, you may be able to test the carry or overflow bits after an addition or multiplication.

Comment: Another method is to use more that one `int` to make a compound integer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Hmm... I have heard my teacher talk about something like that but I can't exactly remember what he said. Could you please explain what a compound integer is. I am quite new to programming.

Comment: A compound integer is one integer made up of smaller integers.  So for example, a 16-bit integer could be made up of 2 8-bit integers.  When the lower integer overflows, the carry is added to the upper integer.  Very similar to adding decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly language-agnostic, since, as you have observed, there are languages that handle integer overflows.

And it has nothing to do with RAM.

It has to do with contemporary CPU architecture and the way integer numbers work. In short, the CPU can work only with certain quantities of bits called a "word". Typically, the registers in the part of the CPU that deal with integers can hold one word. In your example, the word size is 16.

That is, the maximun number (in binary) we can store is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

So, what happens when we add 1 to this?

```
 1111 1111 1111 1111
+0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Well 1+1 is 10 (in binary), so we get 0 in the last position, but have to carry 1 over. This causes the result to be all 0, plus a 1 that is carried over. This 1 is stored in a special place of the CPU, and can be utilized by branch instructions, as long as it is not overwritten by subsequent arithmetic operations. (Usually, this so called carry bit cannot be used in programming languages.)

So what we see here is that the result of 65535+1 results in 0, which seems wrong. 
But we need to get used to the idea that integer arithmetic is done modulo 2^n, where n is the word size in bits. The correct result is 65536, and 65536 mod 2¹⁶ is 0.

I hope your teacher has told you about those basics, otherwise the question would seem unfair.

So, what can happen if you disregard this? You can get wrong results.

How can you solve it? Use two integers to represent numbers that wouldn't fit in one integer. There are many possibilities how to do this. One possibility that is easy to understand but not ideal with regard to memory efficiency would be: Represent the number of days in 2 integers. In the first integer, we count just the thousands. In the second, we represent just the last 3 digits (in decimal notation). For example, to represent 432105, we set the first integer to 432, the second to 105.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU doesn't detect invalid results in all conditions so you have to check them yourself. And then you still have the problem that the math didn't work and you can't do the calculation you want. An alternate solution is to store the data in a larger data structure and implement your own add/subtract/... operations on the structure.

That's what python does and that's why it can store indeterminately large integers natively. Check out python's `decimal` module for another example. There are libraries out there for C/C++ and I presume other languages as well. You could also implement an API on your own - its a bit tedious but doable.